# How to make USB optical mouse work with MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mouse

I just bought a MacBook Air and a cheap Leadership USB optical mouse, which I can't get to work with the MacBook. It works fine with Windows and Linux, and the Macbook Air USB ports are fine. I checked it with USB drive and a Microsoft mouse without encountering any problems.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it supports the standard USB mouse functionality ([HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class)), it should work.  Otherwise, you can use [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) or [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html).  If you have the [Developer Tools](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/) installed, you might also see what [USB Prober](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/apple/mac-os-x/threads/318058) says about the device.

Comment: Those two are what I am looking for but I as expecting I shouldn't need to buy extra software to just plug an standard usb mouse.

Comment: @JhonnyEverson that means it's either not a standard USB mouse, or something is amiss.  Try USB Prober.

Comment: Looking at System Profiler, it shows 'Optical Mouse Device' on USB port but does not work. I installed SteerMouse and it's working fine now. Thanks for your suggestions. PS. I tried 4 usb mouses from different brands before installing that. The only one that worked as MS'.